# Filling gaps in a shower hob - best substance for this gap?

Tags: shower, waterproofing

My shower hob has a number of leaks. I've highlighted a gap in the photo below which appears to be allowing water to run through to the other side of the shower hob. If I use silicone sealant in the position with the red circle it prevents water running off the edge of the hob, so a large pool of water remains which cannot dry out overnight.

Is there a substance I can use to fill the gap circled in red?

I am planning to use a product such as "Shower Plug 220mL" after any other work in an attempt to prevent ongoing leaks.

Note 1: In the photos below, I've placed transparent packing tape over all of the gaps, which I used to test and verify where the leaks were coming from. With the tape on, all but one of the 5+ leaks around the hob stopped.

Note 2: I've let the shower head run in a bucket for a long period of time without any leaks appearing, so I'm not worried about leaks behind the shower itself.

[image: Overall shower view]
[image: Large gap]
[image: No gap]

Comment: tiles aren't waterproof. a waterproof layer is needed behind the tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar problem with the grouting in tiles missing. As we know we are to change the bathroom over the next couple of years, I have filled the gaps with bathroom silicone and smoothed it down with a wet finger.

Comment: I think this is the best answer other than replacing it, which is what we are going to have to do sometime, too.